# Easel.JS > Bitmap larger than canvas... but shows up smaller

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bitmap

In Easel.js I'm putting a bitmap on the screen that's 1920 pixels wide. 
The Canvas itself is smaller (1500 pixels).

However, the Canvas shows the image on the screen and it is not large enough to even reach the edge.

In the code, I'm not scaling the image, the stage nor the container. 
How can I get it to show up in its actual pixel size?

Is Easel.js taking screen-density into account? I didn't see a difference between a "normal" screen and a retina display...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whoops, I'm an idiot. The pivot-point was set in the middle of the image:
bmp.regX = image.width / 2;
bmp.regY = image.height / 2;

Solved it. Sorry to bother you all!